# Wrong type interference in tuples (rest and spread expressions)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm playing with new capabilities in Typescript 3.0 (I'm using 3.1.0-dev.20180717) and found strange behavior with generic types.

```
type Head<T extends any[]> = T[0];
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => 0) extends ((a: any, ...r: infer R) => 0) ? R : never;
type Prepend<A extends any, B extends any[]> = ((a: A, ...r: B) => 0) extends ((...r: infer T) => 0) ? T : never;
type Combine<T extends any[]> = Prepend<Head<T>, Tail<T>>

type test1 = Head<[1, 2, 3, 4]>; // 1 ✔️
type test2 = Tail<[1, 2, 3, 4]>; // [2, 3, 4] ✔️
type test3 = Prepend<1, [2, 3, 4]>; // [1, 2, 3, 4] ✔️
type test4 = Prepend<Head<[1, 2, 3, 4]>, Tail<[1, 2, 3, 4]>> // [1, 2, 3, 4] ✔️
type test5 = Combine<[1, 2, 3, 4]>; // [1, ...any[]] ❌
```

I was expecting, that `test5` will have type `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, because it's same case as in `test4` but wrapped in `Combine<T>` generic type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Might be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was really just a bug [fixed in latest build 3.1.0-dev.20180721](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/25817).